# Java: Standard Practice of Access Modifiers

Tags: java

It is a very basic question through, but I want to explore some of the standards of Java programming languages which shall be followed for a clean and perfect code within the rules set my Java.

I have questions regarding the access modifiers as I have a Class A containing the main method and a util class that contains all the variable declarations, methods and respective handlers. Now, I have extended my util class in my Class A and used all the methods and relevant variables from there.

My questions are:

- I have kept all the methods and variables Public in my util class. Is that fine or I should update the Access Modifiers to private which are only used in util class?
- What about the variables that are used in Class A? I have read a terminology that the variables shall be marked as Private and shall be granted access to the other classes via Methods?

Comment: public, protected or private methods, it depends. Impossible to answer in general. For variables, yes keeping them private and control their access through get/set methods is generally a good habit.

Comment: What about the methods? if any method is required to be used only in the class that it shall be private? or keeping it public is against standard?

Comment: Of course they should be private, no point in granting more access than necessary.